# Default Business Network can be changed on hyperledger Composer Playground installed locally?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to use my local hyperledger composer Playground to make transactions to my Business Network created  and deployed by Composer commands on my local Fabric.

But Hyperledger Composer Playground deploy only on the network called :

```
org-acme-biznet
```

Can I change this and deploy or load into Playground my bussines-network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limitation has been removed in version 0.12.0. Please upgrade to v0.12.0 or higher and you can connect to any deployed business network using the new ID Card feature.

Video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTX-9VyO6OU